# How can I solve "process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)" in opencv - cv2 ( Pycharm & macOS)?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am learning OpenCV but I meet some difficulties, cv2 import is fine but it got error with `cv2.imshow`

```
from cv2 import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', 0)

cv2.imshow('1', img)

cv2.waitKey(100)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And it will get the result:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

My trace tree is too long so I put it in the link below:
https://justpaste.it/1tf4q

Comment: Try using `cv2.waitKey(0)`?

Comment: I have tried `cv2.waitKey(0)`,  `cv2.waitKey()`  and else, but it still got the same result

Comment: have you tried another image?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, it looks like it's a problem of **read or write of a memory**!

Comment: different images but still got the same result

Comment: I read the article but it does not work and I don't even know where is the problem

Comment: The code is very simple, but I cannot run it.  Where can I check the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm faced the same issue and found a link to the issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18079

For now I downgraded OpenCV from 4.4.40 to 4.3.0.36 and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can do it now after I downgrade the OpenCV version to 4.3.0.36, this is really helpful!

Comment: Thanks a lot, spent my complete evening trying to figure out the problem and you turned out to be the saviour.