# segmentation fault in imshow in opencv python3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv, segmentation-fault, imshow

i have installed opencv in python by

`python3 -m pip install opencv-python`

i am currently on macOS 10.15.6

the `pip list` shows  `opencv-python   4.4.0.40` in list

`cv2` has been imported
but it is continously giving

`segmentation error` on the line `cv2.imshow(winname="Face", mat=img)`

the full code is like this

```
import cv2
# read the image
img = cv2.imread("/Users/abhimac/Pictures/mycutout.png")
# show the image
cv2.imshow(winname="Face", mat=img)
# Wait for a key press to exit
cv2.waitKey(delay=0)
# Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the path of image has been checked , it is correct.

Comment: downgrade opencv to 4.0.36 for now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399665/how-can-i-solve-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11/63403479#63403479

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python

pip install --upgrade opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue in `opencv-python` package. Please upgrade to the 4.4.0.42 release. For details, check this issue in OpenCV issue tracker: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18079

Comment: It's happening for me on ubuntu 21.10, python3.9.7 and opencv-python 4.5.4.58

Comment: I had similar problem on Ubuntu 21.10 and Python3.9 and solved it by downgrading to 4.5.3.56

Comment: Known issue in the latest release, see: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/572